# MS Access - Linked Text File Error

Tags: batch-file, ms-access, taskscheduler

I have an access database that points to a linked text file saved in the network. I’ve setup the following:

1. A batch file that opens the DB and runs a macro.
2. A scheduled Windows task that runs daily to kick-start the batch file. The process used to run with no issue, but lately I started getting this error message ‘M:\’ *is not a valid path. Make sure the path name is spelled correctly and you are connected to the server on which the file resides*.
   Please note the following:
3. The windows scheduler runs with no issue.
4. The database opens
5. The Macro runs
6. The process throws the above error message only at the step related to the linked text file.

**The strange thing is that when I run the batch file manually, the process runs like a clock and gets completed successfully (txt file path gets recognized).**

Any idea about how to deal with the above issue? Please

Your assistance is appreciated
Thanks,
Ben

Comment: How exactly is drive M: created?  Is it one of those drive mappings that happens at start-up or logon?  It's possible that your task is running before that mapping is created, try adding a delay to your task configuration.

Comment: StackOverFlow is a place to ask for help about code related issues. Hence the name of the site. You have not defined a question about any specific piece of code you are using

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your M: drive is being mapped as a result of a logon or start-up script.  When taskschedular wakes the machine your script runs before this drive mapping takes place.  Another thing to watch for is the user that runs taskscheduler might not have the same drive mapping as you.  Always run the task manually and investigate any failures.  Running the script outside the environment taskscheduler supplies is only mildly diagnostic.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response.

Please note that I have a proceeding VBA step that renames the same file in the same location and it occurs successfully.

Furthermore, when I engage the batch file manually, the location of linked txt file gets recognized.

Also, after getting the error message, I close the DB, open it again, click on the linked txt file, and it opens successfully.

It is very strange.